# OneNote 2010 shortcut to select Pen #1, OR shortcut to access "Quick Access Toolbar"

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote-2010

Can you assign a keyboard shortcut to the commands you've placed in OneNote 2010's `Quick Access Toolbar`?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or something.

What I really want to do is have a keyboard shortcut to select Pen #1, Pen #2 etc, but since I placed the pens in the `Quick Access Toolbar`, I'd be happy if I could type a keyboard shortcut to access those.

[This is a pretty comprehensive list of known shortcuts](http://www.onenotehelp.com/2009/11/19/keyboard-shortcuts-for-onenote-2010/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  <kbd>F6</kbd>, then numbers appear across the top (overlayed).  Press a number like <kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>6</kbd> to execute items in your `Quick Access Toolbar`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work all the time (the numbers don't like to appear for me).  It appears that this switches the focus around.  How did you find this?

Comment: Just by pushing buttons on the keyboard..

Answer (score 1):

There is an automatically assigned shortcut: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

Comment: The order of the shortcuts in the toolbar determine which shortcut # is used.

Answer (score 1):

For Office 2010 (and other recent versions), press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and numbers/shortcut keys are overlaid on the toolbar (similar to what @bobobobo mentioned as <kbd>F6</kbd> in his answer). Press the respective key (number or alpha), and voila.